# T-SQL reference selecting dates in a query

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL statement

```
Select  * 
from    Policies P
inner join ClientPolicies CP on P.Id = CP.PolicyId  
where   p.Id <> 0
And     P.ProductId = 9
And     (
    P.PolicyEndDate <= GETDATE()
or 
    P.PolicyEndDate is null
    )
```

This pulls back all the values that match the first policyendate is less than getdate, but not the nulls.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (E.g. GETDATE is product specific.)

Answer (score 1):

Change your `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
Select  * 
from    Policies P
left join ClientPolicies CP on P.Id = CP.PolicyId  
where   p.Id <> 0
And     P.ProductId = 9
And     (
    P.PolicyEndDate <= GETDATE()
or 
    P.PolicyEndDate is null
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I knew it a quick question.

Comment: You're welcome. If it's helped, please don't forget to accept it as the answer to help future question askers.